# Obtain key:value from returned JSON string

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm new to jQuery and attempting to obtain data from a SQL database based on the selection of a dropdown. I have managed the AJAX call and it appears as if the data return is a valid JSON format. I cannot figure out, however, how to obtain one of the key:value pairs from the JSON string. I have tried everything I can find by searching the internet:

```
        $("#cmbFacilityName").change(function () {
            $("#hdnMinimumDaysInAdvance").val = ""

            //alert('Selected value: ' + $(this).val());
            if ($(this).val() != '') {

                var organizationKey = $('#hdnOrganizationKey').val();
                var facilitySpaceKey = $("#cmbFacilityName").val();
                //alert(facilitySpaceKey)

                GetMinimumDaysInAdvance(organizationKey, facilitySpaceKey)

            }


        });
```

function GetMinimumDaysInAdvance(organizationKey, facilitySpaceKey) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Facility/View/FacilityReservation.aspx/GetMinimumDaysInAdvance",
                data: { intOrganizationKey: organizationKey, intFacilitySpaceKey: facilitySpaceKey},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {

```
                var obj = response.d;

                //object = JSON.parse(response);



                //var x = JSON.stringify(response);
               // console.log(x.property_actually_now_defined);

                //var obj = response
                //var minHours = obj["MinNbrOfHours"];

             //   var json = $.parseJSON(response);
                //$("#hdnMinimumDaysInAdvance").html(data.MinNbrOfHours);
                   // obj = JSON.parse(response);
                //var parsedJSON = $.parseJSON(response);

                alert('Field: ' + obj.MinNbrOfHours);

               // $("#hdnMinimumDaysInAdvance").val(response.d.MinNbrOfHours);

                //var minNbrOfHours = JSONobj.entity.entries.MinNbrOfHours;
                //alert('Returned value: ' + minNbrOfHours);
                //$("#hdnMinimumDaysInAdvance").text(msg.d)

            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("error:" + JSON.stringify(msg));
            }
        });
    }
```

The method in my code-behind:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
<ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=True, ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
Public Shared Function GetMinimumDaysInAdvance(ByVal intOrganizationKey As Int32, ByVal intFacilitySpaceKey As Integer) As Object


    Dim FacilityRatesBE As New FacilityRatesBE
    Dim FacilityRatesDAL As New FacilityDAL

    FacilityRatesBE = FacilityRatesDAL.GetFacilityRatesByFacilityKey(intOrganizationKey, intFacilitySpaceKey)

    Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(FacilityRatesBE.MinNbrOfHours)

End Function
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me out. I have tried all options I can think of. Obviously, I'm missing or not understanding something.

Comment: Please explain a bit more. Also, have you tried JSON.parse()?

Comment: yes. when i do that i get an error. my research indicated the error was because it is already parsed since the datatype: json is specified in the AJAX call.

Comment: Actually, this statement:Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(FacilityRatesBE.MinNbrOfHours) should be: Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(FacilityRatesBE). The one I posted by accident was another attempt at trying something. I'm actually returning the entire class.

Comment: So let me rephrase the question, you are getting a valid JSON and trying to access some key but somehow that key is not present in the data. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: here is a snippet of whats returned in response: {d: "{"FacilityRatesKey":282,"OrganizationKey":0,"Facil…t":"","NoAlcoholAgreement":"","LastUpdatedBy":""}"}

Comment: The key is in the data: here is part of the reponse: "MinNbrOfHours":2. I'm trying to access the value of that key. So in this case, I'm trying to get the MinNbrOfHours of 2. I have tried many things, along with obj.MinNbrOfHours but I get 'undefined'.

Comment: What error you get when you try to access the property and can you share a working code sample on https://jsfiddle.net/ as that will allow us to look at the problem more closely.

Comment: Also share the complete JSON and Class definition.

Comment: Thanks for responding and trying to help, Pratyush. I got it working per Steve T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment it seems like the value of "d" in your json response is a string, so that you should be able to parse it as

```
var props = JSON.parse(response.d); 
console.log(props.MinNbrOfHours);
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much. I was doing a parse on (response) instead of (response.d).

Comment: Hi @Susan. if this has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. There is no obligation to do this, [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).